# Include jar files in Java project Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am making an application which has dependencies to several files and I would like to be able to include them within the applications file instead of getting the user to manually download them or have a downloader built in.

The IDE I am using is Eclipse and I would rather do this without Maven(I believe this is the kind of thing Maven does but have not looked into this yet).

Thank you for reading.

Comment: so what is your exact question ?

Comment: How to "include" jar files within a project so there is no need for external dependencies.

Comment: Someone needs their upvote privileges revoked.

Comment: I would rather start off simple and Maven seems to get complex quickly.

Answer (score 1):

After adding your jars to your build path, you can export your project as a 'Runnable jar' with the option to package all dependencies into the generated jar. Thus, preventing the user from needing to download the external dependencies. This is the option to select:

[image]

Comment: That makes a executable jar. I'm not sure if that is what the OP wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Open the project properties and go to the Build path settings. There should be an option that says something like include external jars

Answer (score -1):

Right click your Project and select Properties.
Select "Java Build Path".
Select the "Libraries" tab.
Click "Add JARS..." or "Add External JARS..."  depending on your application.